# How To Upload And Display svg Images Using React Node and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on reat, node and mongodb for file(.svg, .jpg, .png) uploading. I'm able to upload and render png and jpg image to the client. But when I upload svg image, it upload to server but cannot render to client.
please Help me ....

Comment: it's not a duplicate question that you refer to..I've seen that question and answer..but that's not exactly what i want..it's alright using svg image from local source..no problem with that..But what My problem is you didn't understand, I asked render svg image from mongodb to front-end client..

Comment: @Nishant I'm going to agree with Karma here and if there is a way possible I will down-vote and report Nishant 's comment because it is very disruptive here. This is NOT a duplicate question and the one Nishant refers to does not even come close to matching what is being asked here.

Comment: @KarmaDorjeTamang did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm searching the entire WWW and can't find anyone or anything relating to this. This typically means there is a very simple and easy answer to this it's just not being explicitly revealed anywhere. I'll keep looking.